# Select statement to extract range of hours from Time String

Tags: select, postgresql-9.3, where-clause

I have a PostgreSQL table like this.

```
city_location |          isp           |   date_    |    time_     
---------------+------------------------+------------+--------------
Cambridge     | Akamai Technologies    | 2014-11-23 | 12:59:37.112
Mountain View | Level 3 Communications | 2014-11-24 | 12:59:37.112
Cambridge     | Akamai Technologies    | 2014-11-24 | 9:59:37.112
Mountain View | Level 3 Communications | 2014-11-25 | 9:59:37.112
```

How can I select ISP and city_location when date_ is 2014-11-24 and time is between 9 and 12.

**I am not interested in minutes, seconds and milliseconds**.
I tried this query which deal only with date

```
select city_location, isp from new_markers where date_='2014-11-24';
```

But, I have no clue how to write select statement for selecting time between 9 and 12 hours.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, I did the following:

Created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Stuff(city_location VARCHAR(30), isp VARCHAR(50), date_ date, time_ time);
```

Populated the table:

```
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Cambridge', 'Akamai Technologies', '2014-11-23', '12:59:37.112');
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Mountain View', 'Level 3 Communications', '2014-11-24', '12:59:37.112');
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Cambridge', 'Akamai Technologies', '2014-11-24', '12:59:37.112');
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Mountain View', 'Level 3 Communications', '2014-11-25', '12:59:37.112');
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Cambridge', 'Akamai Technologies', '2014-11-26', '10:59:37.112');
INSERT INTO Stuff VALUES('Mountain View', 'Level 3 Communications', '2014-11-26', '10:59:37.112');
```

Then run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE time_ BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '12:00:00';
```

or these - same result:

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE time_ BETWEEN '09:00' AND '12:00';
SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE time_ >= '09:00' AND time_ <= '12:00';
```

Personally, I prefer the `BETWEEN` syntax, but that's more a [personal preference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).

Result:

```
city_location   isp                     date_        time_
-------------   ---                     -----        ------
Cambridge;      Akamai Technologies;    2014-11-26;  10:59:37.112
Mountain View;  Level 3 Communications; 2014-11-26;  10:59:37.112
```

As you can see, the query picks out the records between 9 and 12. Just add

```
AND date_ = 'year-mon-day'
```

to filter for your desired date.

Comment: Also make sure that when you say "between 9 and 12" you actually want to include "12:00" but not "12:01", otherwise use `... AND time_ < '13:00'` for hour 12 fully inclusive, or `... AND time_ < '12:00'` for hour 12 fully exclusive.

Comment: It worked. I was declaring time_ and date_ as varchar  instead of time and date. Thank you  @Vêrace.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I added a link to the Postgres docco - `BETWEEN` is inclusive which is what the OP wanted

Comment: @SwateshPakhare **Always** use the correct datatype. Not only will your sorting and filtering not work correctly, you run the risk of confusing the optimiser and slowing the system.